# Rails/Devise - How do I prevent users from seeing sign in page after signing in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a custom sign in form at the landing page of my site. However, since this is the same as the root path, a signed in user will still be able to see it by going through the address bar.

How do I redirect signed in users from seeing the landing page?

### Update: Solution

**routes.rb**

```
  authenticated :user do
    root :to => 'pages#dashboard' , :as => 'authenticated_root'
    # Rails 4 users must specify the 'as' option to give it a unique name
    # root :to => "main#dashboard", :as => "authenticated_root"
  end

  unauthenticated :user do
    root :to => 'pages#welcome' , :as => 'unauthenticated_root'
  end
```

Comment: You don't want user see that sign in form when he logged in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
authenticated :user do
  root :to => "user#index"
end

root :to => "user#sign_in"
```

FYI: http://excid3.com/blog/rails-tip-5-authenticated-root-and-dashboard-routes-with-devise/ may help you understand.